# How to format a DMG (Apple disk image) file?

Tags: macos

I used Apple Disk Utility to make a formatted DMG file. Then there is a reason which prevents me from recreating it, however given read/write permission to the DMG file, I must re-formate it in order to make it usable.

Both disk utility and hdiutil don't seem to be able to format an existing DMG file.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Double-click the .dmg file to open it (mount it). Then launch Disk Utility. In the list of disks and images on the left, you should see the .dmg file, with the mounted version of the volume displayed indented below it. Click on that indented volume to select it, and the main section of the window will now have an "Erase" tab. Click on that tab and you'll be able to use the UI there to erase your disk image.

[image: Disk Utility window showing how to erase a disk image]

Note that Disk Utility isn't great at refreshing the list of disks and images on the left, so if you opened Disk Utility before mounting the disk image, you'll need to quit and re-launch Disk Utility to get the mounted version of the image to show up.

I did this on OS X Mavericks (10.9.2). You didn't say which version of OS X you were running.

Comment: Thanks for the info, unfortunately my DMG file has a damaged partition table and disk utility does not recognize any partition..